# AttributeError: module 'opensim' has no attribute 'Model'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to install setup of OpenSim for "NeurIPS 2019: Learn to Move - Walk Around" this. I have install anaconda 3.7 and first i make a conda environment by using following command.

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and python version 3.6

```
$ conda create -n opensim-rl -c kidzik opensim python=3.6.1
$ source activate opensim-rl
```

then after

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge lapack git
$ pip install osim-rl
```

after successfully running of these commands when i use to run the command

```
$ python -c "import opensim"
```

then I got a attribute error

```
AttributeError: module 'opensim' has no attribute 'Model'
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this error as well, but uninstalling OpenSim and Anaconda and then installing OpenSim 4.2 and Anaconda 2-5.2.0 resolved the issue for me.